# Fancy Border With CSS3

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to create something like this with CSS only, is it possible?

Comment: You can define borders as images so basically any type of border is possible in CSS

Comment: As a 2.5K user, you'll know there is an expectation on Stack Overflow that an attempt is presented, even if it did not work. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 4):

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #006B96;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px #006B96;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: no i just find the right olution of it hen i undelete it with after modifications

Answer (score 2):

```css
div{
 height:50px;
 width:200px;
 background:#006B96;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 4px #006B96;
 border:4px solid #fff;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    box-shadow:
        0px 0px 0px 5px #000,
        0px 0px 0px 10px #fff,
        0px 0px 0px 15px #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gwhq3uk6/

Answer (score -1):

Try to go with Bootstrap and you will no longer have to worry about designing buttons because it is much easier get all kind of buttons and other stuff you need without writing a single line of code.

Comment: Is bootstrap helpful? Yes. Is it the answer to this question? No.